# Find derivative of $x^{x^x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponentiation

Trying to find the derivative of:
$$
x^{x^x}
$$

I have a solution but cannot understand the third transition:
[image: Solution]

Comment: You mean the step $\left( \ln x e^{x \ln x} \right)' = \tfrac{1}{x}x^x + \ln x (x\ln x)'x^x$? That's the product rule. Please specify more clearly what you don't understand if this is not what you mean.

Comment: I'd find it less obnoxious here to write $y = x^{x^x}$ and differentiate $\log \log y$ using implicit differentiation.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Use the product rule

$$(\ln x e^{x \ln x})' = \frac{1}{x}e^{\ln x^x} + \ln x(\ln x + 1)e^{ \ln x^x} = \frac{1}{x} x^x + \ln x(\ln x + 1) x^x$$

Answer (score 2):

$$
x^{x^x} = x^y = e^{y\ln x}
$$

Then the derivative in terms of $y$ is 
$$
\frac{d}{dx}e^{y\ln x} = e^{y\ln x}\left( y'\ln x + \frac{y}{x}\right)
$$
So now you can compute $y'$ right?
Using a similar process.

A quick tip, Always break the problem down into steps when you are learning new techniques :).

Answer (score 0):

Generally ,if f(x) and g(x) are functions than $(u^{v})´=vu^{v-1}u´+u^{v}v´\ln u$

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)=x^{x^{\scriptstyle x}}$ and $g(x)=x^x$, then
$$
\log f(x)=x^x\log x=g(x)\log x
$$
so
$$
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=g'(x)\log x+\frac{g(x)}{x}
$$
Now
$$
\log g(x)=x\log x
$$
so
$$
\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}=\log x+1
$$
Putting things together
\begin{align}
f'(x)&=f(x)\left(g(x)(\log x+1)\log x+\frac{g(x)}{x}\right)\\
&=x^{x^{\scriptstyle x}}x^x\left((\log x+1)\log x+\frac{1}{x}\right)
\end{align}